# Autohotkey when station locked

Tags: windows-7, autohotkey

I'd like to be able to use hotkeys to run scripts when the screen is locked.

I have:

```
^!p::Run, D:\path\to\my\script.bat
```

But if the computer is locked it won't run.

I'm running Win7 64.

Comment: As far as I know, this is a protection method from Windows, nothing AutoHotKey can do about it. Otherwise, you could run a login script while Windows is locked.

Comment: So there's no way I can run my script when it's locked?

Comment: No, you might want to take a look at *task scheduler*.

Comment: But task scheduler run it at certain times, not when I want to

Comment: Not a solution, but the best thing I could offer is to [replace Windows' Ease of access functionality with cmd.exe](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-launch-command-prompt-or-other-programs-using-ease-of-access-button-at-login-screen-in-windows-vista-and-7/). You can then communicate with your script via command line, e.g. with start parameters, without having to log in.

Comment: I knew this trick but it's kind of a security issue

Comment: What issue are you talking about? You could just as easily run only the script itself instead of cmd, doing exactly what you've asked for. I tested it and the script even accepts hotkeys in the lock screen.

Answer (score 0):

AutoHotKey scripts cannot take user input, or raise GUIs while the machine is locked as a security measure. As stated in the comments, you can replace the Ease of Access program with a script or batch, and, when that is run, it can take input, etc. though this opens a potential security issue depending on the functions of your script.